# Recommendations for measuring text in prints and exportations to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I'm developing a multiplatform impressions generator. My goal is that a report is displayed in exactly the same way both in its "Preview" in your "Print", and its "Export to PDF".

In this scenario, I am unable to do the "Export to PDF" look exactly like the "Print". I've already tested some free libraries and despite the same produce beautiful documents, they always have some differences from the "Print" version. And this is due to different methods of measuring the size of the texts.

To fix this, I have to:
 * Isolate the methods that measure the sizes and text positions. Using these same methods regardless of the desired output. ("Preview", "Print" or "Export to PDF")
 * Print each character separately, according to the position determined by the previous step.

So now comes my questions:
 * Is there a simpler approach to this issue?
 * What is the best way to measure the size of each character in impressions? (Without any margins or borders). Below is the method I am currently using, it serves perfectly for when the Graphics comes from a PrintPreview, but if I use Graphics.FromImage (For Pdf), the values returned by these functions change drastically!

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the measured size of the text. (Winouth margins)
/// </summary>
public static SizeF MeasureText(Graphics graphic, string text, IFont font)
{
    GraphicFont f = (GraphicFont)font;

    SizeF rect = GraphicDevice.MeasureSystemText(graphic, '.' + text + '.', f.font);
    SizeF rect2 = GraphicDevice.MeasureSystemText(graphic, "..", f.font);

    return new SizeF(rect.Width - rect2.Width,
        rect2.Height * rect.Height / rect2.Height);
}

/// <summary>
/// Return the measured size of the text. (With margins)
/// </summary>
private static SizeF MeasureSystemText(Graphics graphic, string text, Font f, System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
{
    System.Drawing.StringFormat format = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
    System.Drawing.CharacterRange[] ranges = { new System.Drawing.CharacterRange(0, text.Length) };
    System.Drawing.Region[] regions = new System.Drawing.Region[1];

    format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

    regions = graphic.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, f, rect, format);
    rect = regions[0].GetBounds(graphic);
    return rect.Size;
}
```

Comment: Try the itextsharp NuGet package

Answer (score 0):

Probably the difference you see is the difference in the resolution. PDF always uses 72 DPI (dots per inch) resolution while Windows may have 96, 120 DPI (and so the browser uses this resolution too). Mobile devices may have another DPI (like 264 PPI on Retina and so on).

So while the size in pixels will be the same but the physical size (in inches) will differ depending on the output device's DPI.

For example, the 100 pixels width text object on your screen (with 96 DPI) is the same physical size as 72 / 96 * 100 = 75 pixels width in PDF (with 72 DPI).

TL;DR: check how the pdf component you use handles and recalculates DPI differences and make adjustments in your code when you measure the text size to take in account DPI differences between screen and PDF.

Comment: Well, I have made the individual character measure, as said in the original post. Now I know that have more things involved in this, like the GDI / GDI+ tecnologies! (Try measure "VA" word in PrintDocument Preview and in actual print, the width changes!) So, even the printing isnt allways same as the previewing! So, I cant trust in S.O. hight level measurance....